# how can I validate my nhibernate xml mappings?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate and struggling a bit with it. I am using the latest, version 3.2. I am doing my mapping via the hbm.xml files. I have four entities and four tables.

When I try to run a basic select using LINQ-to-NHibernate, I can pull back two of them but not the other two, leading me to suspect there is some kind of problem with my mappings.

How can I validate these mappings? I am not getting an error, I just get no results back. There is definitely data in the tables.

My query is like this:

```
IQueryable<MyEntityName> results =
            (from x in nhSession.Query<MyEntityName>()
             select x);
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/nhibernate-validator.html)?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also ARE you 100% sure that all hbm.xml files are embedded resources?

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate will throw an error if your mappings doesn't make sense. What could be happening is that you forgot to mark some mapping files as Embedded resource.

Comment: So, I do know about that because I've read the documentation here, http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html, pretty carefully, but you're absolutely right, that is a very common early mistake with XML mapping so I appreciate the response.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error and I have also confirmed with SQL Profiler that for the two entities that aren't working, it doesn't even attempt to submit any query at all to the database.

Comment: In my experience if their is no query then a) mapping fie is not an embedded file or b) you have an error when building the session factory.

Comment: Thanks guys. It turned out to be both a spelling error (i before e except after c, doh!) and in the class element I had used entity-name instead of name. I'll definitely be looking into configuration in code because the XML is kind of a drag.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can offer is grabbing a copy of [Hibernating Rhino's nHibernate Profile](http://nhprof.com/home).  We are 1.5 years into the nHibernate business and it is simply the most important tool we've come across yet.  You can either buy it or subscribe for a period of time for a very reasonable price.  Being able to see exactly what sql your mapping is producing is essential to resolving mapping conundrums.

Comment: I investigated this tool and I don't see that it has any ability to validate my XML mappings.